# Error fetching data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an error "Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\admin\view\add_doctor.php on line 123" when I am trying to execute the following query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_address` WHERE `addr_id` = '$dr_addr'";
```

What could be the possible reasons for such an error? Please help. Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: What is `$dr_addr`?

Comment: becacuse $dr_addr is an array and not a string

Comment: Well, what does `$dr_addr` contain? Do a `var_dump($dr_addr);`

Comment: learn about prepared statements

Comment: Well, I just wanted to know whether there is any error in this line ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments...I have eliminated the error ...